# Converting a HTML/Bootstrap List into a list that Returns a Value in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

New to stackoverflow. I just got into coding and was trying to make my own website using php/html/css. I just started using bootstrap and I created a table with common sports in the U.S.

```
              <div class="panel panel-info">
              <div class="panel-heading">Sports</div>
              <ul class="list-group">
                 <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Baseball</a></li>
                 <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Basketball</a></li>
                 <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Soccer</a></li>
                 <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Tennis</a></li>
                 <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Football</a></li>
                 <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Hockey</a></li>
                 <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Golf</a></li>
              </ul>
           </div>
```

This image is of the table I created.

Instead, I would like to convert this to a form but keep the look the exact same. I have images saved on my server that the user uploads. I have the coding down for displaying the images for each topic but I am struggling to convert this into a get form. I am wanting to display the user the images of the topic clicked... but I just cant get this to work.

IE: User clicks "Baseball", the value "baseball" is "got" and then I sort this way. Any help on converting this to the form I am looking for would be greatly appreciated. Have a nice day.

EDIT AFTER READING COMMENTS: I basically want to obtain a value when the user clicks one of the list group items. For example when clicking "Golf" it would give the value "golf" to me. I initially thought a form would be what I want here but maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

The query-string parameters (key=value pairs after the ? in the URL) are sent to the server under the $_GET property in PHP, so you can use them to pass the clicked element to your server.

```
<li class="list-group-item"><a href="?sport=baseball">Baseball</a></li>
<li class="list-group-item"><a href="?sport=basketball">Basketball</a></li>
<li class="list-group-item"><a href="?sport=soccer">Soccer</a></li>
...
```

```
<?php 
$sport = $_GET['sport'];
```